# Actively scan my screen for a certain color and execute a keyboard command when scanned

Tags: java, colors, screen, scanning

I am trying to write some code that actively scans the screen for a specific color , the color should only appear in a very specific part of the screen. When scanned in do some code. I've seen some people use the robot class in which they take a screenshot and scan that , but i need it to be actively scanning the screen in real time. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you constantly take screenshots and analyze them in parallel? It wouldn't be very efficient, but would work.

Comment: huh , im not sure ? id prefer it to be fast like in the milliseconds. Im not sure if it would be able to cap it process it and execute the command fast enough.

Comment: My first thought was to take the screen shot, stick it in a queue, then process each screen shot in a thread pool. I can't quote how fast it would take though, as that would depend on a lot of things.

Comment: interesting , ill look into it